# Unable to delete object from Django admin panel with MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have a Django project using a MongoDB connected by Djongo. I created a simple model which looks like:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)
    include_on = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    format_example = models.TextField(blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

After registering the model by using the line `admin.site.register(Property)` in the `admin.py` file I end up seeing my model appear. After adding a test `Property` I see the line

```
The property “Property object (61226db9f4f416b206c706e5)” was added successfully.
```

Which tells me the item was added. It also appears on the admin panel but it looks like:

```
Property object (None)
```

If I select the property I get an error that says:

```
Property with ID “None” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?
```

If I try to delete the property I get a `ValueError` with error of:

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'.
```

Since I am currently learning Django/MongoDB I actually ran across the ValueError once before. The fix was to delete the entire database and start over. The issue is I don't want to run into this in the future and want to know what I have to do to fix it, or correct what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. Turns out I need to assign a primary key. I fixed this by changing my model to..

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=128, blank=False)
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)
    include_on = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    format_example = models.TextField(blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
```